# Spring boot 2 exceptions stacktrace incomplete

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot 2 reports exceptions in test different than v1.

Stacktrace report using spring boot 1.5.18

```
Running com.test.v1.TestStacktrace
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.test.v1.TestStacktrace
test(com.test.v1.TestStacktrace)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at com.test.v1.Util.willThrowException(Util.java:15)
  at com.test.v1.TestStacktrace.test(TestStacktrace.java:20)
```

With v1, you get the whole stacktrace, starting for the line where the exception is actually thrown `Util.willThrowException(Util.java:15)`

Stacktrace report using spring boot 2.0.6

```
Running com.test.v2.TestStacktrace
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.022 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.test.v2.TestStacktrace
test(com.test.v2.TestStacktrace)  Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.test.v2.TestStacktrace.test(TestStacktrace.java:20)
```

With v2, you only get `TestStacktrace.java:20`, which is the last line in the exception stacktrace. If stacktrace has 5 levels of method, having only last caller takes more time to identify root cause.

Does anyone know who to fix this or what steps can be done to have exceptions reports as they are with version 1?

Update: This is how TestStacktrace.java file looks

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.test.v1;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 *
 * @author Jhovanni <jhovanni@github.com>
 */
public class TestStacktrace extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Util util = new Util();
        util.willThrowException(null);
    }
}
```

`Util.java` only contains an static method which directly throws and exception when called. `TestStacktrace.java` v1/v2 are almost identical, only changing package name. Both projects are recently created using spring initializr, with the only difference (apart from package name) is spring boot parent version in `pom.xml`.

Comment: can you please update your question with TestStacktrace.java file?

Comment: What is the difference between `com.test.v1.TestStacktrace` and `com.test.v2.TestStacktrace`?

Comment: Hi @GauravRai1512, I added TestStacktrace.java from v1 project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Boris, com.test.v1.TestStacktrace.java from is identical to com.test.v2.TestStacktrace.java.
The only difference in both projects, aside from package name, is spring boot parent version declared in pom.xml
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is related to an IDE, not intrinsic to spring project. Question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the test I can see that you use **JUnit 3** style:

```java
public class TestStacktrace extends TestCase
```

**JUnit 4** has made obsolete the JUnit 3 requirement of making a test class a [TestCase](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html) subclass. You should use the [@Test](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html) annotation to represent a test:

```java
public class TestStacktrace {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that for testing Spring Boot applications the only dependency you need is this Starter:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It includes JUnit, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) for more details.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TestCase, and in fact is not related to the question. I am extending TestCase not because I require it to represent a test, but because I want to automatically has access to assert functions without importing them explicitly.
But like I said, it is not related to the question. But thanks anyway, I found the issue and added as a comment for others with same problem: "it is an IDE bug"